# renaming a particular link element attribute and deleting with comparison

Tags: jquery

I have this `unordered list`created dynamically and would like to get the data-name attribute value of a link element inside the list element of the unordered list,compare it to array values from resoponse object, then delete the whole list element in which it lies if it is not in array otherwise, rename it.

```
<ul id="hithere"class="image-list">
   <li class='image-list'>
      <div class='controls'>
         <a href='#' class='image-list' data-name='myname'><img src='stop.png' ></a>
      </div>
      <span class='name'>myname12</span
   </li>
   <li class='image-list'>
      <div class='controls'>
         <a href='#' class='image-list' data-name='myname2'><img src='stop.png' ></a>
      </div>
      <span class='name'>myname1312</span
   </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my jQuery where iam comparing all the list elements to the array  cookedJSON and altering the data-name attribute if it is in the array to "uname"; that's in array.if it is not ,then i delete that list in which the link is.

```
 function work(i,fly,response){

    cookedJSON=[];cookedJSON.push({ uname : response.uname , Oname : response.Oname });
$("li.image-list").each(cookedJSON, function(i,arr) {
      if($(this).find('a[data-name]').attr('data-name')== arr.Oname){
        $(this).attr('data-name')==arr.uname ;}else{$(this).detach();}
    });
```

it is not changing the data-name to the new value and also does not delete.why?I would like it to rename and also delete that
particular list element,leaving all the rest intact.

Comment: console.log is your friend

Comment: `$("li.image-list").each(cookedJSON..` this syntax is wrong. Read the documentation

Comment: hi – Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy ,what is the correct syntax please?

Comment: You can get it here.. http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: hi,  mplungjan .what do you mean??

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing two statements of looping i.e

```
$.each(arr,function(key,value)
{
    // accessing array element
});

and

$('#selector').each(function(index)
{
   // accessing DOM element
});
```

adjust it according to your requirements.BTW there is no need of nesting the loops.

This will do the trick

```
$('#selector').each(function(index)
{
   cookedJSON[index].Oname; 
});
```

Comment: I there a way of using them together?like for loops can be nested

Comment: thank you for all your time and effort.i have managed to avoid the whloe list items fromm disappearing by:for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
  $('#hithere li').eq(i).remove();} and now iam going to try renaming using the same method